# how to scale the video to be played on screen to mobile device

Tags: css

my problem is my desktop website is working fine. but I have made a video which is not able to view properly on the mobile device. I want it to view to full screen while it comes to mobile device

Comment: Can you show some code?. You properly need to add codec

Comment: We currently have no idea how your website is designed, how mobile display is treated (if it is), so only thing we can say is "set it to the good dimensions with CSS or anything"

Comment: ok thanks , my problem got fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.
CSS:

```
.video-size video
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<div class="video-size">
<video  autoplay loop controls muted>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```